# How to write ArrayList<Double> into a file in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I want to write the `ArrayList<Double>` array into the file in such a way that when I double click on the file then the file opens and the user can read the data.

I have tried the `DataOutputStream` & `RandomAccessFile`; both works fine but when I double click on the file it shows data which is not in readable form.

I tried this:

```
ArrayList<Double> larr=new ArrayList<Double>();
larr.add(5.66);
larr.add(7.89);
try{
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("out.txt");
    DataOutputStream dos =  new DataOutputStream(fos);  
    for(Double d:larr)
        dos.writeDouble(d); 
    dos.close(); 
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

But now the case is that when I open the file `out.txt` by double clicking on it. It comes in non-readable form.

Comment: @Lok - use a PrintWriter .... specifically `PrintWriter.print(double)`

Comment: @ray I tried that,but it is of no use; as in Files.write it is accepting a char sequence.

Comment: @Lok: You'd get a lot more help if you had followed the basic rules of posting questions. For example, you should've provided a [Minimal-Complete-Verifiable-Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to provide code for others to look at if you expect any reasonable amount of help and also show that you've actually tried researching something rather than asking right away after getting stuck.

Comment: @Stephan I tried `PrintWriter.print(double)` but don't you think it will print only on console as my file remains empty.

Comment: @downshift but I also want that when I open the file by double clicking on it, then it should come in human readable form.

Comment: @ray please see now.

Comment: @Lok - Incorrect.  PrintWriter can be used to write to any output sink.  Read the javadocs ... sepcifically the list of constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) to get human readable values to `out.txt` (and I would specify the parent folder, personally; I like the user's home directory). Also, I would *prefer* a [`try-with-resources` close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and a *method*. Something like,

```
public static void writeList(List<Double> al) {
    File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "out.txt");
    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f)) {
        for (Double d : al) {
            pw.println(d);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also, you could **declare** and **initialize** `larr`<sup>**1**</sup> in one line like

```
List<Double> larr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5.66, 7.89));
```

<sup>**1**<sub>And please program to the `List` interface.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

It's because the I/O streams you said you tried to use (`DataOutputStream` and `RandomAccessFile`) are treating the numbers as binary data, rather than text. You should use a `PrintStream`.

Example:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new File(filePath));
ps.println(5.25);
ps.close(); // Be sure to close the stream when you're done with saving the numbers
```

Noticed something familiar with `ps.println(5.25)`? `System.out.println(5.25)` does *exactly* the same thing to the console.